# Javascript creating predesigned table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Is there a way to create a new table in javascript by inserting a pre-designed table?

I am comfortable creating tables in javascript however I wanted to create a large table that had quite a bit of text and various rows etc so I was wondering is it possible to insert a pre designed table when creating a new table?

I have no idea is this is even possible

I hope that I can grab a table written in plain html and insert it into a page via a click of a button using javascript.

Comment: Sure it's very possible do you actually have any code to fix?

Comment: It's a very broad question. Essentially you just need to read about creating and using templates with JS. The template could be a table... or it could be any other HTML element(s).

Comment: ok thanks after searching adding "HTML" rather than "tables" with javascript I think adding html (which in my case is a table) into a <div> is pretty straight forward.  I have found an example where large blobs of HTML are hidden inside <script> tags which has an id.   That blob is then inserted into a <div> with a click of a button. Seems to be just what I am after.